# Explanation of proof for eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix A corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From the following:

http://www.quandt.com/papers/basicmatrixtheorems.pdf

The following theory has an explanation :

> Theorem 2. The eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix A corresponding to
>   different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other. Proof . Let i 6=
>   j . Substitute in Eq. (5) first i and its corresponding eigenvector
>   xi, and premultiply it by x0 j , which is the eigenvector
>   corresponding to j . Then reverse the procedure and substitute in (5)
>   the jth eigenvalue and eigenvector and premultiply by x0 i.
>   Subtracting the two results from one another yields (i − j )x0 ixj =
>   0, from which it follows that x0 ixj = 0

BTW (5) is the basic eigenvector equation:

> Ax=λx

A proof that fills in some missing/(obvious?) steps above would be appreciated.

For example the "substitute in (5) .. and premultiply" is not clear to me.

Here is what I come up with - which is incomplete:

> x_j*A*x_i  - x_i*A*x_j = x_j*λ_i*x_i - x_i*λ_j*x_j

I do not know how to reduce that equation further.

Comment: Just repeat the caluculation from the proof of thm 1 with $\lambda, x$ relaced by $\lambda_i$ and $x_i$ and  $\bar\lambda, \bar x$ replaced by $\lambda_j$ and $x_j$ -- then use that in the resulting equation (corresponding to (7)) the lhs is again $=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ be eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix $A$ with corresponding eigenvectors $x_i$ and $x_j$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)\langle x_i,\, x_j\rangle \\
=&& \lambda_i\langle x_i,\, x_j\rangle - \lambda_j\langle x_i,\, x_j\rangle \\
=&& \langle\lambda_ix_i,\, x_j\rangle - \langle x_i,\, \lambda_jx_j\rangle \\
=&& \langle Ax_i,\, x_j\rangle - \langle x_i,\, Ax_j\rangle \\
=&& \langle Ax_i,\, x_j\rangle - \langle A^Tx_i,\, x_j\rangle \\
=&& \left\langle (A-A^T)x_i,\, x_j\right\rangle \\
=&& 0
\end{eqnarray}
and thus $\langle x_i, x_j\rangle = 0$.

Quandt constructs equality between the third and the fifth line directly. He also uses the notation $xy$ instead of the more abstract $\langle x,\, y\rangle$ that I prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I am unfamiliar with the scalar multiplication rules for the inner product operator: specifically the step:  = ⟨λixi,xj⟩−⟨xi,λjxj⟩ . Will try to find some reference breaking this down further.

Comment: I appreciate the details above and have upvoted.

Comment: The following reference on inner product spaces is filling in the gaps I was missing:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_i$, (resp. $x_j$) an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ (resp.$\lambda_j$) then

$$\lambda_i \langle x_i,x_j\rangle= \langle Ax_i,x_j\rangle=\langle x_i,Ax_j\rangle=\lambda_j\langle x_i,x_j\rangle\implies \langle x_i,x_j\rangle=0$$
since $\lambda_i\ne\lambda_j$.

Comment: This is, strictly speaking, not the explanation of the proof in the paper but a proof on it's own...